# How do I add an image to the turtle screen without getting an error?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, attributeerror, python-turtle

I have seen other people ask this question and I have looked it up. However, I still get the same error. **Error: 'str' object has no attribute '_type'**. Here is my code:

```
from turtle import *
setup(600,600)
Screen()
sc = Screen()
alien = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/AlienGameImage.gif")
sc.register_shape(alien)
t = Turtle()
t.shape(alien)
mainloop()
```

I have also tried:

```
sc.addshape(alien)
```

Comment: That code works fine for me, where are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried your code and i had the same error, with few changes it worked perfectly for me :

```
from turtle import *
sc = Screen()
sc.setup(600,600)
alien = r"folder\giftest.gif"
sc.register_shape(alien)
t = Turtle()
t.shape(alien)
mainloop()
```